# Problem with OO programming in javascript and ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, web-services, oop

I'm trying to keep as much OO as possible, but ASP.NET AJAX seems to be doing something strange after returning from the server...

```
function Person( personId ) {
var id = personId;
var firstName;
var lastName;

this.initializeStep1 = function() {
    PeopleServices.getFirstName(id, this.initializeStep2);
}

this.initializeStep2 = function(foundFirstName) {
    alert(foundFirstName);
    firstName = foundFirstName;
    PeopleServices.getLastName(id, this.initializeStep3);
}

this.initializeStep3 = function(foundLastName) {
    alert(foundLastName);
    alert(firstName);
    lastName= foundLastName;
} 

this.initializeStep1();
```

}

This is the basis of it. So basically it is creating a person and retrieving their first and last name from the server in order to initialize the person.

When I create a new person, it goes through initializeStep1, calls the server webmethod getFirstName, and eventually reaches initializeStep2. the alert(foundFirstName); works, it alerts the name that was found and it is correct... now after setting the private variable firstName to what was found, I make a second call to the server...

This time, it does not reach initializeStep3, and I know it shouldn't have failed on the server end because even if I replace the line

```
PeopleServices.getLastName(id, this.initializeStep3);
```

with

```
PeopleServices.getFirstName(id, this.initializeStep3);
```

it still does not work.

I was wondering if after the first server call it lost the reference to "this" or something similar to that happened where I cannot call initializeStep3 the way I am. Anyone have any ideas?

some notes:

- I know the server webmethods are all working, I've tested them individually.
- I'm not sure if my OO is right here.
- I'm not sure if I'm going about AJAX right either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I hope this is just an example, because in the real world, there would be no reason to just not return an entire Person.

Comment: It is. What I am dealing with cannot be made into an object to return more data without it making no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a closure

```
var that = this;
PeopleServices.getFirstName(id, function (x) { 
                                    that.initializeStep3(x);
                                } 
);
```